# Simple jQuery if else statement

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement

I have a mini script, this script finds within a specific class the link. I basically need a simple if-else-statement. Something like if **a** is existing, then run the script if not, then do nothing.

Can someone help me with that?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".click-child", function() {
      var href = jQuery(this).find("a").attr('href');
      window.location = href;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, this is what I imagine you're asking for.  If you could put your HTML somewhere it would be more clear what you're looking for.

jQuery has a `.find()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/find/) which searches the parent selector for a child selector, if it finds the child selector, you can use it as a normal jQuery selector. Otherwise, it'll do nothing.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please add a little more detail, and I'll see if I can help your out more.

```
<section class="cards">
    <div class="card">
        <img />
        <h3>Opens link</h3>
        <a href="https://google.com">Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <img />
        <h3>Nothing should happen</h3>
    </div>
</section>

<script>
    jQuery(window).ready( function() {
        jQuery('.card').click(function() {
            const link = jQuery(this).find('a').attr("href")
            
            if (link) {
                window.location = link;
            }         
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This is exactly what I needed. Changed the class according to my specifications and it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:has()` selector to only hook the event handler to the `.card` elements which contain an `a`. Then you don't need the `if` statement at all. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("body").on("click", ".click-child:has(a)", function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
    window.location = href;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an if/else. You can do an `.each()` over a list (which might either contain one element, or be empty):

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("body").on("click", ".click-child", function () {
    jQuery(this).find("a").first().each(function () {
      window.location = this.href;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `.first().each(` does this sound normal to you?

Comment: @Dropout Yes, otherwise I would not have written it. `$("a").each()` where there is only one `<a>` works the same way, and there is nothing "un-normal" about that, either. `.first()` is just a way of making sure that there will only be a single item for processing.

Comment: *Strictly* speaking, it won't make much of a difference, since the page ends as soon as you do `window.location = this.href;`. But semantically speaking, it transports the sense that the page `window.location` will be set to the first link found (if any).